# more than one user edit authorised-keys

Tags: ssh, openssh, authorized-keys

I would like to have two users to be able to edit my authorised_keys file.
Is this possible?

I have tried to add the user to the original user etc/group this didn't work.

e.g.
user1:xx:user2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/group` lists group ids, not user ids. If you're on a system where each user is given their own group (user1:user1), this is ok, otherwise create a new group and put both users in it.

In any case you'll also need to make sure that the `authorized_keys` file belongs to the group in question (use `chown` if necessary), that it is group-writable (`chmod g+w authorized_keys`), and that user2 has execute permission for all the directories on the path leading to `authorized_keys`.

PS. When you're done, it is possible that your ssh might decide the file is unsafe and refuse to read it. In that case your work will be in vain, but you can always set up a setuid program to edit the file.

Comment: when I add a second user or a group ssh stops working.
I cannot use a setuid program as its another server which is trying to edit the file and using scp to do so.

Comment: Bingo: ssh stops working by design, out of security considerations. Why not just add a key allowing the second user access to the same account? if he can modify your authorized_keys file, he'll have full access to the account anyway.